# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException при отправке e-mail по smtp

Tags: android, email

Для отправки email использую код из статьи  [Отправка E-Mail средствами Android](http://habrahabr.ru/post/112450/). На одном компьютере у меня отправка нормально работает в эмуляторе и на реальном устройстве тоже, импортировала проект на другой компьютер - не работает. Лог вот такой:

```
Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465; 05-21 12:16:08.705: I/exception(394): nested exception is: 05-21 12:16:08.705: I/exception(394): javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
```

Пожалуйста, подскажите по какой причине не работает? И как это исправить. Сама предполагаю, что ошибка в `JSSEProvider.java` ( т.е. на компьютере, где запускаю что-то не установлено):

```
import java.security.AccessController;
import java.security.Provider;

public class JSSEProvider extends Provider {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public JSSEProvider() {
    super("HarmonyJSSE", 1.0, "Harmony JSSE Provider");
    AccessController.doPrivileged(new java.security.PrivilegedAction<Void>() {
        public Void run() {
            put("SSLContext.TLS",
                    "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.SSLContextImpl");
            put("Alg.Alias.SSLContext.TLSv1", "TLS");
            put("KeyManagerFactory.X509",
                    "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.KeyManagerFactoryImpl");
            put("TrustManagerFactory.X509",
                    "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.TrustManagerFactoryImpl");
            return null;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: я бы не рекомендовал писать свой e-mail клиент, а отправлять посредством стандартного.
то есть предлагать пользователю отправить имейл с уже введенным текстом на уже введенный адрес.   По сути ему только останется нажать кнопку "отправить"

Comment: Почему не рекомендуете? У меня в этом необходимость, вот http://hashcode.ru/questions/221130/android-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-e-mail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш комп пытается установить защищенное SSL соединение с хостом gmail, но не получается по причине того, что сервер на той стороне не видит ни одного корневого сертификата в вашем компе, которому он бы мог доверять:

> Trust anchor for certification path not found.

Надо либо установить таковой сертификат на компе, либо работать с другого компа

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, где взять такой сертификат и как его установить? Мне обязательно нужно, чтобы работал на ноутбуке.

Comment: @Asy без понятия... Если я чего-то правильно понимаю, то установщик должен устанавливать этот сертификат при установке Windows. У вас видимо самопальный Windows...

Comment: @Asy поройтесь [так](https://www.google.com/#q=gmail+certificate+install)